# "It / may / might/ could be dangerous"

Tags: modal-verbs

> Friend: "I want to go to the jungle."

Which answer is should I choose?

> 1) I: "Be careful. It **may** be dangerous."
>
> 2) I: "Be careful. It **might** be dangerous."
>
> 3) I: "Be careful. It **could** be dangerous."

Is there a difference between these modals in this context? (especially between may and might)

Comment: All three are ungrammatical. They are modal verbs, and cannot have the verb **'s** (=_is_) before them. All three modals are possible in this context.

Answer (score 1):

In the form

> Be careful. It might be dangerous.

All three modals are possible, with little difference in meaning (in this case). Using "could" is probably the most common form. Using "may" preserves the traditional distinction between can (for ability) and "may" for possibility and permission. Using "might" is correct. It also expresses possibility.

There is really no difference in meaning.

Comment: The lexical verb just was a typo (a moment which I didn't give an attention) but I knew it well before. That's why I edited it because it turns us from the main question. Anyway I would like to learn from you the little difference between them if you don't mind:)